# how to create a fillable pdf form that can grow dynamically

Tags: pdf, adobe

Is there a way to create a fillable pdf form that can grow dynamically.

the requirement is .. i have a website where users will download fillable pdf forms and report their expenses. the expenses can range from 1 to 10000 or even more.

is there a way to achieve this?

-Vivek

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a fillable form is necessarily the best solution for this. It's possible to have fields that expand in height and width but you are giving the users free form boxes and may make your processing of the expenses more difficult.

Have you considered writing a simple web app to handle creating expenses instead?